# Como limitar o número de casas antes da vírgula em uma expressão regular?

Tags: java, regex

Estou usando esta expressão para não deixar o usuário digitar ponto antes de qualquer número e limitando 2 casas depois da vírgula, mas eu precisava também limitar 5 casas antes da vírgula, do jeito que está eu posso inserir quantos números quiser antes da vírgula. Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso? estou apanhando aqui.

Minha expressão: `"([0-9]+(\\.)?([0-9]?[0-9]?))"`

Comment: Tipo assim? `\d{1,5}(\.\d{1,2})?` (1 a 5 dígitos, e opcionalmente o ponto seguido de 1 ou 2 dígitos) P.S. Esses grupos são de captura? Ou tanto faz?

Answer (score 2):

Da mesma forma que você fez pra limitar depois:

```
"([0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?(\\.)?([0-9]?[0-9]?))"
```

Ou seja, o primeiro é obrigatório, e os 4 seguintes são opcionais. No entanto, eu tenho algumas sugestões pra melhorar essa regex:

1. Use as chaves para escolher o número de vezes que um elemento vai se repetir. `exp{n}` significa que a expressão precisa ocorrer exatamente `n` vezes. `exp{a,b}` significa que ela precisa ocorrer no mínimo `a` e no máximo `b` vezes:

   ```
   "([0-9]{1,5}(\\.)?([0-9]{0,2}))"
   ```
2. Se esses grupos não forem de captura, eu sugiro removê-los, pois isso complica desnecessariamente a regex:

   ```
   "[0-9]{1,5}\\.?[0-9]{0,2}"
   ```
3. Desse jeito ainda é possível se ter um ponto sem nenhum dígito na frente, ou nenhum ponto e dois dígitos a mais. Ligue o ponto aos dígitos, e exija ao menos 1 dígito se o ponto estiver presente:

   ```
   "[0-9]{1,5}(\\.[0-9]{1,2})?"
   ```
4. Você pode usar `\d` (escapado, `\\d`) para representar um dígito, em vez do intervalo `[0-9]`:

   ```
   "\\d{1,5}(\\.\\d{1,2})?"
   ```
5. Se você quiser evitar zeros à esquerda, separe o caso do `0` com o caso de `[1-9]` seguido de 0 a 4 dígitos:

   ```
   "(0|([1-9]\\d{0,4}))(\\.\\d{1,2})?"
   ```

Comment: vlw pela resposta, mas nenhum funcionou. O que acontece é que estas expressões deixam eu colocar se eu tiver digitado até 5 números. Elas aceitam mais de 5 números, e depois do 6° número não deixa mais eu digitar ponto.

Comment: @daniel12345smith O problema deve estar na forma como você está usando então, e não na expressão em si. Pois as expressões estão corretas, veja [esse exemplo](http://rubular.com/r/9ssoaGRUwt). Se precisar de mais ajuda, mostre o código Java onde você usa essa expressão.

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que esta possa lhe satisfazer: 
`/^(\d{1,5})?(\.\d{1,2})?$/`

Aqui seque um exemplo em `HTML` da validação:

```js
$('input').keyup(function(e){
  var val = this.value;
  var test = /^(\d{1,5})?(\.\d{1,2})?$/
  
  if(test.test(val)){
    $("p").html("Válido.")
  }else{
    $("p").html("Inválido.")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="12345.67"/><br>
<p></p>
```